# Returning a Promise from a Computed Property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I realize there have been several questions similar to this, but none of those answers seems to be resolving my issue.  My objective is to take a list of `language`'s, and filter them so that my template can display a subset of the full list.

I started off by verifying that my computed property is working:

**MyController.js**

```
// Works as expected
languagesFiltered: function() {
   return this.get('languages');
}.property('languages')
```

Then I added in a filter function, but here's where I ran into trouble:

**MyController.js**

```
languagesFiltered: function() {
   // console.log shows that languages is actually a promise
   var languages = this.get('languages');

   // all of this returns a promise, but Handlebars can't handle the promise
   return languages.then( function( languagesArray ) {
      return languagesArray.filter( function( item, index, enumerable) { 
         return item.get('name') !== 'English';
      });
   })
}.property('languages')
```

I'm attempting to use the `Ember.Array.filter` method (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_filter).  The filter seems to be working correctly, but now `languagesFiltered` returns a promise, and Handlebars can't handle that.

I tried one last alternative:

**MyController.js**

```
languagesFiltered: function() {
     var languages = this.get('languages');

     // "return languages;" works
     // But "return languages.filter" returns an empty array
     return languages.filter( function( item, index, enumerable ) {
         console.log(item);
         return true;
   });
}.property('languages')
```

And `console.log(item)` never gets called.  So my questions are:

- What is the best way to implement the simple filter I'm after?
- This is a read-only computed property, but what are best practices for handling async values in computed properties?

I'm using Ember 1.7.0-beta4, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta10, and ember-cli 0.44.  I'd upgrade to Ember 1.7.0, but there's a small bug that affects another part of our app, so we're waiting until 1.7.1.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try returning a [`PromiseArray`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html) instead of just the promise.

You should be able to do something like..

```
languagesFiltered: function() {
   // all of this returns a promise, but Handlebars can't handle the promise
   var promise = this.get('languages').then( function( languagesArray ) {
      return languagesArray.filter( function( item, index, enumerable) { 
         return item.get('name') !== 'English';
      });
   })

   return DS.PromiseArray.create({
      promise: promise
   });

}.property('languages')
```

Comment: Thank you, @tikotzky! Your solution worked perfectly. I didn't realize that when I have an array of promises, I can actually wrap them in `DS.PromiseArray`.

Comment: You are actually wrapping a single promise in the `DS.PromiseArray`. Its a single promise that resolves to an array. If the promise resolved to an object then you would need to use `DS.PromiseObject`

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. It's interesting that I can return `this.get('languages')` directly, but any manipulation of `this.get('languages')` must be wrapped in a `DS.PromiseArray`. Can you explain this?

Comment: `ember-data` actually returns a `DS.PromiseArray` when you do `this.get('languages')`. You should be able to confirm this by runnning `console.log(this.get('languages').toString())`

Answer (score 3):

Now there are few better solutions. I use [ember-promise-helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers).

So can keep your `languagesFiltered` code intact and do the following inside your hbs:

```
{{#each (await languagesFiltered) as|lang|}}
 ...
 ...
```

More – https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/

Comment: Thanks, Removed comment and voted your post. Take care next time