# findAll with a property defined by parent

Tags: ember.js, dynamic, parent, record, findall

2 components, 1 parent 1 child. The parent is a list with buttons. User clicks the button and the child editor becomes visible and the variable listType gets passed to the child from the parent.

I want a property to do a findAll in the child based on the listType property, e.g.

```
listType:null,
records: this.get('store').findAll(this.get('listType'));
```

problem is when the child editor first inits listType is undefined and takes a moment for the data to be passed down from the parent. How should I compute the records based on the listType so that it can dynamically change records when a different listType is selected from the parent list and not crash when the listType property is undefined on init?

This might seem a little weird but I have 20 different listTypes and being able to compute records this way will save me from having to create an additional 40 files to save and delete the model types required.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_what-are-computed-properties) in your child component which is able to react to a missing listType.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  store: service(),
  listType: null,
  records: computed('listType', function () {
    if (!this.listType) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.store.findAll(this.listType);
  }),
});
```

`records` is going to return a promise and you will have to handle it this way in your template. I personally use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/40180704/796999.

Another option could be passing `records` into the child component instead of looking them up there. You would create the computer property the same way and just change your parent template to have 
`{{child-component records=records}}`.

Comment: Ok got the computed property to work. Issue now is the child component hbs does not recompute and display data in the DOM.

`{{#each records as |item|}}`
does not iterate in the child

Comment: I just added some information on rendering a promise, let me know if that helps.